# Plugin Paths Issue

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am using a plugin which has several instances where it is using a hardcoded path rather than using the WP function to find a path. The problem here is that it's referring to wp-content but I've changed the WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME setting in the wp-config file (there was a past requirement to do that).

Anyways, is there a way to achieve this without updating the plugin codebase itself (i.e. allow it to be upgradable in the future). I guess this goes with the whole idea of extending a plugin without having to edit the codebase.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin developer might include the changes into the core plugin if you submit the changes or offer a patch.  You can't be the only one out there with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Codex has a very useful page on [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) which looks like it may be just what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, this is the very reason why hardcoding this into a theme or plugin is bad. I think your best option is to fork it using git/hg then merge any new changes yourself, which is not always practical.